# Add generic types to an object key and retrive it later based on the key

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Trying to save the generic type inside a class private object and then use that type to the returned data.

```
class CreateApi {
  private endpoints: any = {} // type?

  addEndpoint<Data>(key: string) {
    this.endpoints[key] = key // how can we assign 'Data' type to the specific key
  }

  getOne(key: string) {
    const data = {} // here the data should be of type 'Data', based on the selected key
    return data
  }
}

type User = { id: string }

const api = new CreateApi()
api.addEndpoint<User>('users') // we can add as many endpoints as we need

const data = api.getOne('users') // data should be of type 'User' without forcing it
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)